# error: undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, imread

I'm new to Qt and I have a project that needs to configure OpenCV in Qt , I tried to run a simple code in Qt but I got this error "undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)`"
and here is my code...

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main(){
Mat src,gray;
src=imread("C:/Users/user/Desktop/wood-pattern.png",1);
imshow("gg",src);
cvWaitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

and my source.pro is

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-08-24T20:38:56
#
#-------------------------------------------------
INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\include\
CONFIG(release,debug|release)
{
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x86\vc11\lib\opencv_calib3d249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x86\vc11\lib\opencv_contrib249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x86\vc11\lib\opencv_core249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x86\vc11\lib\opencv_features2d249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x86\vc11\lib\opencv_flann249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x86\vc11\lib\opencv_gpu249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x86\vc11\lib\opencv_highgui249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x86\vc11\lib\opencv_imgproc249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x86\vc11\lib\opencv_legacy249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x86\vc11\lib\opencv_ml249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x86\vc11\lib\opencv_objdetect249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x86\vc11\lib\opencv_ts249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x86\vc11\lib\opencv_video249.lib
        }
CONFIG(debug,debug|release)
       {
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_calib3d249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_contrib249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_core249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_features2d249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_flann249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_gpu249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_highgui249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_imgproc249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_legacy249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_ml249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_objdetect249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_ts249.lib \
        C:\opencv\opencv2.4.9\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_video249.lib \
}
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = Source
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
```

I saw all the answers about but they didn't work.
my Qt is 32bit and my Windows is 64bit.
I think my configuration is wrong. I followed many tutorial but they weren't for OpenCV 2.4.9 so please help me ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See output of `pkg-config opencv --libs` to find out what libraries you're missing, then add them to your config.

For me, the full list of libraries is

```
/usr/lib64/libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib64/libopencv_contrib.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib64/libopencv_core.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib64/libopencv_features2d.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib64/libopencv_flann.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib64/libopencv_gpu.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib64/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib64/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib64/libopencv_legacy.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib64/libopencv_ml.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib64/libopencv_nonfree.so.2.4.8    # you don't have this one
/usr/lib64/libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4.8
/usr/lib64/libopencv_photo.so.2.4.8      # this one
/usr/lib64/libopencv_stitching.so.2.4.8  # this one
/usr/lib64/libopencv_superres.so.2.4.8   # and this one
/usr/lib64/libopencv_ts.a
/usr/lib64/libopencv_video.so.2.4.8
```

Comment: actually my code just need highgui and imgpro library.Is it important that my windows is 64bit and qt is 32bit ? what should I exactly write in source.pro? should I add dll.a libs?

Comment: As far as you compile in 32, your libraries have to be 32 bits, too

Answer (score 0):

No idea about Windows, but if it has `pkg-config`, you should be able to get QMake to use it automatically by adding

```
PKGCONFIG += opencv
```

to your project file (assuming that your OpenCV installs the correct package-config files as it does on sane platforms).

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was solely the order of parameters, note that

```
g++ main.cpp -o main `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv`
```

works while

```
g++ -o main `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` main.cpp
```

doesn't since the latter defines what `main.cpp` needs **before** `main.cpp` is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the Qt-creator , I use Vim instead .So i created my own commands that work just fine .
this is my cv2run custom command content :

```
 #!/bin/bash 

file=$@

if [ "${file: -4}" = ".cpp"  ]; then 
        g++ $file -I/opt/robots/pepper/ctc-linux64-atom-2.5.10.7/opencv2/include/ -L/opt/robots/pepper/ctc-linux64-atom-2.5.10.7/opencv2/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_videoio 
    if $status ; then 
        ./a.out && rm -rf a.out
    fi
else
    echo "This Command should be used only with cpp files that uses the opencv library !!"
fi
```